# Do each of the Rubies have a dominant personality trait?

Tags: steven-universe

I've only started watching *Steven Universe* from the last episode of Season 2 but in the episode *Hit the Diamond* I noticed that each of the Rubies that arrived looking for Jasper appear to have a dominate personality trait. For instance, the one with the Ruby in her eye seems to be the more aggressive one while another one appears to be more of a ditz/scatterbrain.

When I learned that Garnet is actually a Gem Fusion, I began thinking that Ruby's personality trait has something to do with her and Sapphire's feelings for one another: they spent most of the match flirting with one another and it was their running into each other's arms (more Sapphire running into a stationary Ruby) which blew their cover. However, when Sapphire's Ruby was trying to convince the other Rubies not to search the barn she seems awfully nervous so maybe this was her true personality trait and it's just covered up when she's with Sapphire (love conquers fear).

So I am wondering, do all the Rubies (including Sapphire's) have a dominant personality trait? If so what are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Each Ruby appears to have a unique personality but not necessarily a dominant personality trait. In general, Rubies appear very emotional (as compared to Sapphire, who appears quite composed). Each Ruby, in addition to having emotional natures, may utilize their abilities based upon their age, experience, and personalities.

It seems that Rubies are not known for their perception or overall intelligence (since they are easily tricked by Amethyst pretending to be Jasper), instead they would seem to be primarily foot-soldiers or shock troops especially when they merge to become a giant fusion Ruby.

- The Ruby which is a part of Garnet is our first exposure to the Ruby personality. Garnet's Ruby is passionate, emotional and inclined toward extreme outburst. Garnet's Ruby is very devoted to Sapphire and would do anything to protect her from harm. She is the Ruby we have had the most experience with until the Ruby Army appears in the third season. Garnet's Ruby is a member of the Crystal Gems who was originally a Homeworld Gem soldier 5,750 years ago. She made her official debut in "**[Jail Break](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Jail_Break)**".

The Ruby Army which appears in the third season episode: "**[Hit the Diamond](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Hit_the_Diamond)**" gives us five new Rubies to experience. Instead of all being fiery and passionate as Garnet's Ruby, the Ruby Army instead has diverse personality traits. Their designation were given to them by Steven based on where their gems were placed on their bodies.

- **Ruby (Army):** Militaristic, physically adept, displays superhuman strength, gem on upper arm.
- **Ruby (Doc):** Intelligent (comparatively speaking) and the leader of the group and most well-versed in Gem lore. Prone to giving directions to the other Rubies. Her gem is in the center of her chest.
- **Ruby (Leggy):** Shy, the newest of the Rubies, she seems confused and least willing to do anything without instruction. Her gem is on her left thigh.
- **Ruby (Navy):** Highly emotional, appears to be more sensual and interested in the Earth. Her gem is in her navel.
- **Ruby (Eyeball):** Stoic, commanding but polite; oldest of the Rubies in the group, complete with the knowledge of the base on the moon.